# Azure web job How to edit its schedule

Tags: azure, web, edit, jobs

I have made a Azure web job which invoke power shell, how can I edit it once it is built?
By edit I would mean
1.Change the ps script that have  i uploaded as a zip file. 
2 Change the schedule of the web job
 Thanks in anticipation

Ajay

Comment: For Editing the schedule see this post [Modify scheduling on Azure WebJob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485225/modify-scheduling-on-azure-webjob)

Comment: Use App Service Editor to amend the CRON value in `settings.job` file; I have answered in the Link which @DiegoB shared

Answer (score 0):

1. You can edit the ps and upload the zip again.
2. Go to the scheduler in Azure management portal and you change the interval there

Good luck